# Contactor wiring for cistern well with two floats

Tags: wiring, well

I have a cistern well with a float switch to protect pump from low water. There is also a float switch at storage tank that turns on when water is needed to fill tank.

I am in a very remote area and my installer and only one I know in area has just passed away. He installed the components to a 30amp  Eaton c25 definite purpose contactor.

How would this be wired. I replaced the contactor as it failed. I say it failed because we ran out of water and when I opened the panel I smelled burnt wiring. The 2t1 connection was charred and burnt.

I replaced with exact replacement part but once I turned on power the contactor sucked in and worked for maybe 5 minutes. I was in the process of calibrating the pumptec plus that is also in the panel, when it lost power and it seems that the contactor will not “reset”. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

I am going to deconstruct what is there as you can see from the picture there are a lot of wires that I assume was from previous versions of the system. Also there is a jumper that is the white wire on top with yellow terminals that looks wrong to me. That’s why I would like any help. That is exactly how the other contactor was wired thanks again.

[image: inside of wiring panel]

Comment: I added some line breaks to try to make that wall of text easier to read. Please consider doing so when you write - it helps make your communication more clear.

Comment: I see things that fail all the time and because it failed folks try to rewire things, it worked stop rewiring and find out what failed, look at all the dirt in that box I would bet the old contactor was buzzing and heating up because it was dirty and or rusted, rust on the mag keeps it from pulling in all the way, buzzing can hammer the contacts if bad enough and toast the components, check the float switches they fail also and could have ran the pump dry no lubricant of water the pump over heats drawing more power through the mag things start smoking, find the root cause.

Comment: An update, I found out the float valve in cistern is actually not even hooked up. I bypassed the contactor and filled the tank but the pumptec plus three lights are blinking and it won’t let me do calibration. So if I bypass the contactor where would I wire the float pump at?

Comment: Ed Beal, I explained why it failed, also    I rewired exactly the same with the exact same relay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it appears that the first thing to fail was not the contactor. The connection was burnt because it was subjected to excessive current demand.

Most probably the pump motor is shorted or the pump has ingested some debris and is jammed. You need to find out from the pump manufacturer what the stalled or startup resistance of the pump motor should be.

Unfortunately you may have damaged two contactor sets. Repair the pump before sacrificing another contactor.

Comment: I made the presumption that "injected" should have been "ingested".

Comment: Thanks for the response Freeman, question: after bypassing contactor to fill the tanks, for the family that lives there, the pump worked and we got the tanks filled. Would you still pull the pump? Thanks again.